# RecyclerView onBindViewHolder not painting my views

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Im sorting when clicking my items, but after they are sorted the fill color of the favorite icon is not set or disapears, this is what I'm doing

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final LineViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Line line = lines.get(position);
 holder.line_name.setText(line.getName());
     holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (!Utils.userLogged()) {
                        showLoginInviteDialog();
                    } else {


                        if (!line.isFavorite()) {

                            holder.favoriteFilled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            line.setIsfavorite(true);
                            //order
                            Collections.sort(lines, new LineComparator());
                            notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } else {
                            holder.favoriteFilled.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            line.setIsfavorite(false);
                            Collections.sort(lines, new LineComparator());
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                    }


                }
            });
}
```

And this is the issue[image]

Comment: post your complete onBindViewHolder code

Comment: it justs has this only two lines more above final Line line = lines.get(position);
        holder.line_name.setText(line.getName());

Comment: check answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following line after `holder.line_name.setText(line.getName());`

```
if (line.getIsFavorite()){
    holder.favoriteFilled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    holder.favoriteFilled.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Comment: just used a ternary operator, I think its better  holder.favorite.setBackgroundResource(line.isFavorite() ? R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24px : R.drawable.baseline_favorite_border_24px);